# NSubstitute not implementing publish method of IMediator

Tags: .net, mocking, cqrs, nsubstitute, mediatr

I have this method that creates an instance of a Pipeline Behavior to validate a command

```cs
        internal PipelineBehavior<TCommand, bool> CreatePipelineBehaviorValidator(IValidator<TCommand> validator)
        {
            var cache = Substitute.For<IMemoryCache>();
            var bus = Substitute.For<IMediator>();

            IEnumerable<IValidator<TCommand>> validators = new List<IValidator<TCommand>> {validator};

            return Substitute.ForPartsOf<PipelineBehavior<TCommand, bool>>(cache, validators, bus);
        }
```

and inside PipelineBehavior i uses the mocked bus version that i pass to the PipelineBehavior class constructor to publish an ExceptionNotification

```cs
 _bus.Publish(new ExceptionNotification(error.ErrorCode, error.ErrorMessage, error.PropertyName));
```

but when i run the test, and tries to execute the Publish method of the _bus object it throws me an

```cs
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task MediatR.IMediator.Publish(!!0, System.Threading.CancellationToken)'.
```

NSubstitute doenst create the publish method?

I tried to use `ForPartsOf<IMediator>()` but it accepts only class, not interfaces

Comment: Have you tried adding the [NSubstitute.Analyzers](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/nsubstitute-analysers/) package to your test project? It may help to detect if a non-virtual call is causing issues. Also is it possible to use a real `PipelineBehavior` with mocked dependencies instead of a partial mock?

Comment: I will check out on this ``NSubstitute Analyzers``.

I tried to use the real PipelineBehavior with mocked dependencies, but the constructor receives an IMediator, and i tried to send a ``Substitute.For<IMediator>()`` to the pipeline's constructor and it throws me the above answer exception :(

Comment: Just found MediatR author [recommends integration tests](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/issues/476#issuecomment-568776954).